# Flex 4 TextInput prompt styling

Tags: css, flash, flex4, prompt, textinput

I'm developing a web application in Flex, and I've hit a bizarre brick wall right at the end - the *prompt* of the TextInput class/component, which I style like this:

```
s|TextInput:normalWithPrompt {
    color: #CCCCFF;
    fontStyle: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
}
s|TextInput:disabledWithPrompt {
    color: #CCFFFF;
    fontStyle: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

...is not accepting either custom fonts, nor is the color property working. Other styling properties seem to work, it only seems to be the two I need that don't! Has anyone experienced anything like this before? The color property is over-ridden by the base color property, I can extend the class to get around this but seems like I'm reinventing the wheel doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be working for me: I couldn't tell the difference between the normal color of the prompt text and what you've specified, but when I changed it to red the prompt text was red. Same thing w/the font (I changed it to `Times New Roman` and it seemed to change). What doesn't change is the actual text (ie: if you type something in the text input, it's not red). Are intending only to change the font/color of the prompt text or also the text that the user enters?

Comment: If I use a custom embedded font, it doesn't work, just defaults to Arial. And even with Arial, specifying a colour doesn't do anything, the only way to change it is with the TextInput::color property, which I don't want to do